# How to add custom header containing the absolute address of the originally requested resource

Tags: haproxy

I have the following setup:

```
                 |-------|--- backend1:8080
example.com:80---|HAProxy|--- backend2:8080
                 |-------|--- backend3:8080
```

I would like to configure the HAProxy to add a custom header containing the original url. For example if the user requests `http://example.com/foo?bar=baz`, i.e.:

```
GET /foo?bar=baz HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com:80
```

I would like the HAProxy to translate this request to the backend like so:

```
GET /foo?bar=baz HTTP/1.1
Host: backend1:8080
x-custom-header: http://example.com/foo?bar=baz
```

The [`reqadd`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#4-reqadd) option only allows me to add a header with a static value. I was able to get the path portion from the request using [`reqrep`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#4-reqrep):

```
reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ ([^\ ]*)\ (HTTP\/1\.[10])  \0\r\nx-custom-header:\ \2
```

but unfortunately this captures only the path portion of the original url resulting in the following header:

```
x-custom-header: /foo?bar=baz
```

So my question is whether it is possible in HAProxy **1.4** to combine both the `Host` header and the first line of the HTTP request into a custom header

Comment: Have you tried combining `reqadd` with an acl that references the `be_id` (backend-id)?  It's not precisely dynamic but it might get you closer if the number of backends is small... `reqirep` also supports an optional acl, so you could possibly write separate regexes for each back-end, each active only if an acl matches the selected backend-id.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can't do this in **HAProxy 1.4**.

---

However, for those finding this question on 1.5+:

In HAProxy 1.5+ you can reference variables via the `%[variable]` syntax and you're not restricted to only using static strings. You can see which variables exist already in [section 7.3](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#7.3) of the HAProxy configuration guide (specifically [7.3.6 for layer 7 variables](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#7.3.6)).

For your case, you're looking at raw `url`, like this:

```
http-request set-header X-Custom-Header %[url]
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my conclusion that this is not possible in 1.4. I have switched to `nginx`.

Comment: %[url] is not always the full URL, but it does appear to be the best haproxy can do. haproxy 1.8 URL variable docs: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#7.3.6-url